# Translating and outputting AJAX object request

Tags: ajax, event-handling

I have a form which send a POST request to a specified RESTful service if the username and password are correct it will return

```
Object {status: "success", message: "Welcome!"}
```

and if there is an error it will return

```
Object {status: "error", message: "Incorrect username or password."}
```

both in the console via

```
console.log(data)
```

is there a way I can take these objects and access them and do something for each response e.g. show an element etc.

Please find my code below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            'username': $('#username').val(),
            'password': $('#password').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: 'URL HERE',

            data: formData,

            success: function(data) {
                // Here's where you handle a successful response.
                console.log();
            },

            error: function() {
                $('#error').show().text("There seems to be a problem logging in.");
            }
        })



        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data);

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        e.preventDefault();


    });
});


<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="URL HERE">
                        <label id="error">Sorry it seems your credentials are incorrect</label>
                        <div class="inputBlock">
                           <label for="username">Username</label>
                           <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputBlock">
                           <label for="password">Password</label>
                           <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />
                     </form>
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the properties of the returned object using Javascript

```
    //In your done function just treat "data" like an object
    .done(function(data) {

        if(data.status === "success"){ 
            //Do something
        }
        else if (data.status === "error"){
            //Display error
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I wanted to get the message string how would i go about outputting this?

Comment: @HarryBerry You can access the message with `data.message` but ultimately it depends on where you're trying to display it, if you are trying to write it to a webpage you will need to manipulate the DOM to display the value in the web page, if you are just trying to log it to the console, you can do `console.log(data.message)`

Comment: Yeah I have worked that out. I am trying to display it to the webpage but when I use $('body').append(data.message); I get Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Comment: @HarryBerry Try posting your updated code in a new question, its not productive to try and chain answers in the comment section.